# Getting jquery.validate { ignore: } to work for fieldset contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, filtering

I'm using the jQuery.validate() plugin for a form. However the form contains a fieldset (which is hidden, and used as a template for adding rows to the form) which I don't want to be validated. The fieldset will be named something like `organisation_contacts_tmpl_33` with the invariant being the `_tmpl_` part. I've tried:

```
$('#myform').validate({
  debug: true,
  ignore: '[id*="_tmpl_"] input'
  });
```

I've even renamed the fields inside the fieldset to start with `tmpl_` and tried:

```
$('#myform').validate({
  debug: true,
  ignore: '[id^="tmpl_"]'
  });
```

(and multiple variations thereof) but to no avail . Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just ignore hidden elements?

```
$('#myform').validate({
  debug: true,
  ignore: ':hidden'
});
```

Comment: Because they're not hidden! Only the containing fieldset is hidden. (Plus I think validate already ignores :hidden )

Comment: "However the form contains a fieldset (which is hidden ...) which I don't want to be validated." - So is it hidden or no?  And I don't believe validate ignores hidden elements by default - only disabled ones: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate .

Comment: @Dycey - `:hidden` is a visibility check, it doesn't by default ignore `:hidden` and the child elements are `:hidden` as well, so this looks like the approach you want.

Comment: Yup, i was reading the source, and mentally (wrongly) seeing `.not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]")` as `.not(":submit, :reset, :image, :hidden")` Apologies to Dr BBonifield!

Answer (score 2):

its just a jQuery selector that it expects  see the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)

this should work...

```
  $('#myform').validate({
    debug: true,
    ignore: '#fieldset_id input'
  });
```

Comment: Yeees, except I'm generating #fieldset_id programmatically, and dynamically across lots of differen pages...